# how to start api app on intellij without tomcat or any type of server?

Tags: api, intellij-idea, web-deployment, vert.x

I have an API app created using vert.x framework , i am able to build the application but not able to run . when i try to run the app , i automatically get redirected to the "cucumber.api.cli.main not found error" . I delete the automatic configuration but next time i try to run the app it gets generated . What is the configuration i should run on.

I have tried to research about this , but most of the questions and answers asks me to set up tom cat server or glass fish server which i don't want to do .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hello world application using IntelliJ Idea, vert.x -

**Verticle :**

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

import static com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.LOGGER;

public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        .end("<h1> Hello Vert.x </h>");
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept)
      .listen(8070, http -> {
        if (http.succeeded()) {
          LOGGER.info("Started Server at port 8070");
        } else {
          startFuture.fail(http.cause());
        }
      });
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      req.response()
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        .end("Hello from Vert.x!");
    }).listen(8888, http -> {
      if (http.succeeded()) {
        startFuture.complete();
        System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 8888");
      } else {
        startFuture.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });
    router.route("/test").handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type","text/html")
        .end("<h2> This is another end point with same port </h2>");
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8070,http ->{
      if(http.succeeded()){
        LOGGER.info("Another server started 8070");
      }else{
        startFuture.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    LOGGER.info("Shutting down application");
  }

}
```

**Main Method to deploy Verticle**

```
import com.testproject.starter.verticles.MyVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class MyVerticleTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertex = Vertx.vertx();
    MyVerticle myVerticle = new MyVerticle();
    vertex.deployVerticle(myVerticle);
  }
}
```

Now you can follow the below URLs - 
1. http://localhost:8888 
2. http://localhost:8070/test

The application doesn't required to have tomcat to run.

Reference : https://vertx.io/docs/

Useful links - https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-awesome